# input value change based on a input value

Tags: angular, typescript

I try different methods, but I can't really figure it out how can I solve this.
So, I want to type a number to a input, and multiply that number, and displaying on another input.

Html file:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Work fee net</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Work fee gross</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled (change)="getGrossFee($event)" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Ts file:

```
   export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {
   workNetFee: number=0;
   workGrossFee : number =0;


  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getGrossFee(val){
 this.workGrossFee = val
 return val = this.workNetFee * 1.27;
  }

}
```

I know it's a basic question, but I try to improve my angular knowledge.
Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to changes to the first input, so you can update `workGrossFee` and display it on the second input with `[ngModel]="workGrossFee"`

```html
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Work fee net</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="getGrossFee($event)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Work fee gross</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="workGrossFee" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {
   workNetFee: number=0;
   workGrossFee : number =0;

  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getGrossFee(val){
    this.workGrossFee = val * 1.27;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- at app.module.ts  add `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`
- also , at app.module.ts add FormMoudle to imports  `imports :[FormsModule]`
- 

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Work fee net</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" (change)="getGrossFee()" [(ngModel)]="workNetFee" name="workNetFee" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Work fee gross</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled [(ngModel)]="workGrossFee" name="workGrossFee" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 workNetFee: number=0;
  workGrossFee : number =0;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }

 getGrossFee(){
  
 this.workGrossFee = this.workNetFee * 1.27;
 }
```

Comment: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ngmodel-two-way-data-binding-in-angular/#:~:text=The%20Angular%20uses%20the%20ngModel%20directive%20to%20achieve,and%20ngModelChange%20which%20binds%20to%20the%20input%20event.